# How to proceed further in this Eigen Boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I have the following eigenvalue BVP
$$
\lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F = 0
$$ wit BC(s) $F(0)=0,\frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\beta_h,\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$

$\mu$ is the eigenvalue parameter. For $\lambda_h=0.02,\beta_h=10$, I solved this eigen value problem numerically using the *chebfun* method in *MATLAB* to attain the follwoing 6 EVs

$\mu=-32.9463,-28.6002,-24.5873,-20.8885,-17.4846,-14.3643$

I took one of the eigenvalues $\mu=-32.9463$ and made a charcteristic equation from the BVP as:

$$0.02x^3-0.4x^2+24.9463x+100=0$$ which gave me three roots.
$-3.74207, (11.871-34.5722i), (11.871+34.5722i)$

***How should i proceed further to reach a solution form ?***

I know that probably i need to guess a solution structure considering a real root and two complex and then proceed further to find the constants which will be three in this case because of the cubic nature of the ODE.

***How many of EVs i need to consider ?***

Also there will be three linear equations because of the three BC(s).

But i doubt won't this all just give me a trivial solution ?

***Attempt***

I tried the follwing:

the three roots $\delta_k(\mu),\ \ k = 1,2,3$ we have the general solution form as

$$
F(x) = \sum_k C_k e^{-\delta_k(\mu)x}
$$

using now the boundary conditions

$$
F(0) = \sum_k C_k = 0 \longrightarrow (1)
$$

and with

$$
F'(0) = -\sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)\\
F''(0) = \sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)^2\\
$$

giving

$$
-\frac{\sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)^2}{\sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)}=\beta_h\longrightarrow (2)
$$

and similarly

$$
-\frac{\sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)^2e^{-\delta_k(\mu)}}{\sum_k C_k \delta_k(\mu)e^{-\delta_k(\mu)}}=\beta_h\longrightarrow (3)
$$

then we have three linear equations $(1,2,3)$ in $C_k$ that can be arranged as

$$
M(\mu)\cdot C = 0,\ \ C = (C_k)
$$

I arrive at the following 
linear equations

$$C_1+C_2+C_3=0$$

$$\frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\frac{{C_1}{\delta_1(\mu)}^2+{C_2}{\delta_2(\mu)}^2+{C_3}{\delta_3(\mu)}^2}{-{C_1}{\delta_1(\mu)}-{C_2}{\delta_2(\mu)}-{C_3}{\delta_3(\mu)}}=\beta_h$$

$$\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\frac{{C_1e^{-\delta_1(\mu)}}{\delta_1(\mu)}^2+{C_2e^{-\delta_2(\mu)}}{\delta_2(\mu)}^2+{C_3e^{-\delta_3(\mu)}}{\delta_3(\mu)}^2}{-{C_1e^{-\delta_1(\mu)}}{\delta_1(\mu)}-{C_2e^{-\delta_2(\mu)}}{\delta_2(\mu)}-{C_3e^{-\delta_3(\mu)}}{\delta_3(\mu)}}=\beta_h$$

This could be rearranged in the form of $M(\mu).C_k=0$, which becomes a system of linear equations with $C_1$,$C_2$,$C_3$ as unknowns.

Here $\delta_1(\mu)$, $\delta_2(\mu)$ and $\delta_3(\mu)$ are the three roots i mentioned above which were found after substituting the first eigen value $-32.9463$

But when i try to solve this system of equations I get $C_1=0$, $C_2=0$ and $C_3=0$. (I solved it using *matlab* $AX=B$ solver)

Is there something really silly i am doing wrong here ? or is my assumption of the solution form misplaced ?

I must mention that there are infinite number of negative EVs and *chebfun* returns these 6 calling it the smoothest eigenmodes

Comment: Using the two conditions at endpoint $0$, you should get a one-parameter family of solutions.  If your eigenvalue is really correct, these should all satisfy the condition at endpoint $1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael from one parameter do you mean with "one undetermined constant" ? Can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I made an attempt to solve the problem. Have edited the original question to reflect it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Update: I also tried the Evans Circle method for finding eigenvalues using a Mathematica function and get the same Eigenvalues. They still give me a trivial solution. I cannot figure out at all what i am doing wrong.